# How to create a pool of Apache HttpClients with varying SSL client auth certificates

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have been stumbling through the Apache doc and other examples trying to create a client that uses Apache HttpClient to make calls to various RESTful web services. (Each of these web services potentially requires a different client certificate for authentication). Initially I have created a static code block that initialises a HttpClient (with SSLContext info and a pooling connection manager):

```
private static CloseableHttpClient _client;
static {
  HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClients.custom();
  SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SSLContexts.custom();
  sslContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
  sslContextBuilder.loadKeyMaterial(new File("clientcert.p12"), password, password, (aliases, socket) -> aliases.keySet().iterator().next());

  SSLContext sslContext = sslContextBuilder.build();
  HostnameVerifier allowAllHosts = new NoopHostnameVerifier();
  SSLConnectionSocketFactory connectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, allowAllHosts);
  clientBuilder.setSSLSocketFactory(connectionFactory);

  RegistryBuilder<ConnectionSocketFactory> regBuilder = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create();
  regBuilder.register("https", connectionFactory);
  regBuilder.register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory());
  Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = regBuilder.build();

  PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
  clientBuilder.setConnectionManager(connectionManager);
  _client = clientBuilder.build();
}
```

At this point I can use the client to execute requests and the client authentication works fine as long as the server is configured to allow access to clientcert.p12.

What I need is to be able to dynamically change the client certificate per request based upon the value of the required client certificate.

Is it possible to reuse a static HttpClient whilst dynamically changing the client certificate? Also if this is possible am I still going to see the performance benefit of using the pooled connection manager?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an undocumented `http.socket-factory-registry` execution context attribute one can use in order to override connection socket factories set up by the connection manager at construction time.

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setSSLContext(SSLContexts.createSystemDefault())
        .build();

SSLContext customSSlContext = SSLContexts.custom()
        .loadKeyMaterial(new File("my-keystore.jks"), "sectret".toCharArray(),  "sectret".toCharArray())
        .build();

Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
        .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
        .register("https", new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(customSSlContext))
        .build();

HttpClientContext clientContext = HttpClientContext.create();
clientContext.setAttribute("http.socket-factory-registry", socketFactoryRegistry);
try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("https://host/stuff"), clientContext)) {
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
}
```

Use with extreme caution when using the same client instance / same connection pool to execute requests my multiple threads with different user identity / security context.

Comment: Unsure why this question and answer don't have ALL the upvotes. Saved my life! In a microservices world, where multiple services can be called from one service, using multiple certificates, this is good to know!

Answer (score 4):

I'm posting here my solution using `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` class, this one worked for me:

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
                new DefaultHostnameVerifier());

```
    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory> create()
            .register("https", sslConnectionFactory)
            .register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
            .build();

    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLContext(sslContext)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build())
            .setConnectionManager(cm)
            .build();

    cm.setMaxTotal(200);
    cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
    final ApacheHttpClient4Engine engine = new ApacheHttpClient4Engine(httpClient);
    engine.setFollowRedirects(false);

    ResteasyClient client = clientBuilder.httpEngine(engine).build();
    ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromPath(
            "https://my.server.com/mtls/protected/resource"));
    String response = target.request().get(String.class);
```